# TYPO3 extbase: how to use ObjectStorage?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I'm trying to use a m:n relation, the same way as FrontEndUser is related to FrontEndUserGroup, e.g. without intermediate mm table. In my controller, I build my object, then I call `$barRepository->update($barObject);` to update the values of my object. However, it fails on the update function with the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Cbrunet\Up\Domain\Model\Foo::getPosition() in /home/cbrunet/websites/typo3_src-6.1.1/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Backend.php on line 486
```

where `Foo` is the type of the object contained in the ObjectStorage of Bar. My understanding is that `getPosition` should be called on the `ObjectStorage`, not on the object contained into that `ObjectStorage`. However, I cannot figure out why this is not working in my case.

This is in TYPO3 6.1.5. Any hint would be appreciated.

---

The model of `Bar` which has a m:n relation to `Foo` looks like:

```
namespace Cbrunet\Up\Domain\Model;

class Bar extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {

/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Cbrunet\Up\Domain\Model\Foo>
 */
protected $myprop;

public function __construct() {
    $this->myprop = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
}

/**
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $myprop
 * @return void
 */
public function setMyprop(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $myprop) {
    $this->myprop = $myprop;
}

/**
 * @param \Cbrunet\Up\Domain\Model\Foo $myprop
 * @return void
 */
public function addMyprop(\Cbrunet\Up\Domain\Model\Foo $myprop) {
    $this->myprop->attach($myprop);
}

/**
 * @param \Cbrunet\Up\Domain\Model\Foo $myprop
 * @return void
 */
public function removeMyprop(\Cbrunet\Up\Domain\Model\Foo $myprop) {
    $this->myprop->detach($myprop);
}

/**
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage
 */
public function getMyprop() {
    return $this->myprop;
}
}
```

The relevant code in my controller looks like:

```
/**
 * action update
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function updateAction() {
    $args = $this->request->getArgument('myargs');
    foreach ($args as $k=>$val) {
        $pp = $this->barRepository->findOneByAprop($k); // another prop of Bar, not illustrated in the code above.
        $listepour = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
        foreach ($val as $p) {
            $ap = $this->fooRepository->findOneByUid(intval($p));
            $listepour->attach($ap);
        }
        $pp->setMyprop($listepour);
        $this->barRepository->update($pp); // error occurs here
    }
    $this->redirect('list');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Do you also have configured your TCA?
- do you have an *initStorageObjects*-function in your domain model?

Also you can try to build these case with the extension-manager and compare the code.

Comment: The missing part was the `initStorageObjects` function. Where is it documented? Why does FrontEndUser doesn't have this function?

Comment: because *frontenduser* has in his *construct*-method the same call like the *initstorageObjects*

Comment: but its a good question where it is documented!? thatswhy it is usefull to use the extension-manager to compare some settings

Comment: Indeed, I too wonder where such things are documented. I feel that after ExtBase and friends entered the arena it has become much harder to code for TYPO3. I love the framework and indeed the evolving codebase, but I find it hard to maintain steam when so much time goes into trying to work out how to do things. I would love reference grade documentation, but even a few links in the source saying "We discussed this here-and-here" would go a long way!